# Edit the name of existing sprint in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

**Question**

Is there a way and if so how do you change the Sprint name of an existing Sprint in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

> First Method

If you are using the new navigation go to your

Select "Project settings" in the Lower left corner of the project View.

**Project-settings -> Boards -> Project configuration -> 'Iterations'**

Now you should see your iterations. Right-click the iteration To Edit.

> Second Method

**Boards -> Sprints -> Click Date-range**

above the Sprint name near the upper right side of the screen to edit the name of the current sprit

Comment: added second Methoed

Comment: Thanks for the second method @WizardHammer. It's really weird UX that you click on the date range to edit the Sprint name! I couldn't find it for looking!

Answer (score 14):

You can do  that in following way:

***Click on Project-settings ==> Boards ==> Project configuration ==> Iterations***

See the screen shot for better clarity.

[image]

***Alternative Way:***

It can also be achieved in following steps:

***Boards ==> Sprints ==> Set Dates (Fill out date range here)***

See the screen shot for better clarity:

[image]

Hope that would help